# JPA 2 : Implicit column reference in the @MapsId mapping fails

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, jpa-2.0

i am try to use Multiple Mapped Attributes . but when i try to run the code , the code will generate the exception, this example is based on Pro JPA 2 , Chapter 10 book . there is following code :

**DeptID.java**

```
public class DeptId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5177373337405448966L;
private int number;
private String country;
    .....................
```

**ProjectId.java**

```
public class ProjectId implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4239980609226293562L;
private String name;
private DeptId deptId;
.....................
```

**Department.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(DeptId.class)
public class Department implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private int number;
@Id
private String country;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="deptId")
List<Project> projects;
    ......................
```

**Project.java**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ProjectId.class)
public class Project implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private String name;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="dept_id")
private Department deptId;
    ........................
```

this code will generate the follwoing exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Implicit column reference in the @MapsId mapping fails, try to use explicit referenceColumnNames: example.domain.Department
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DeptID has two primary keys, so you cannot have something like `@JoinColumn(name="dept_id")`. Instead, use this :

```
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="dept_number", referencedColumnName="number"),
    @JoinColumn(name="dept_country", referencedColumnName="country")
})
```

If this still doesn't work: in primary key classes (DeptID & ProjectId) try to switch to public or protected the private attributes. Also check that they have a constructor without arguments and implements equals & hashcode methods.