# Struggling to map Entity Class to Database table with composite key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class that i am attempting to map to a Microsoft SQL server database table. The table has a composite key primary key consisting of three values namely:

1. a regular numeric value
2. a foreign key (numeric) that refers to another table
3. a foreign key (numeric) that refers to another table.

In other words, i am referring to an association table that links two tables(entities), and to do so i am using JPA, Hibernate and Springboot.

Since we are dealing with composite keys, i have created a separated class annotated with @Embeddabled that is used in my entity class.

The problem is that, in attempting to execute the app, Spring throws at me the following exception: Implicit column reference in the @MapsId mapping fails, try to use explicit referenceColumnNames:

Here is my embedded id class

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class RoleIdEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "IDEPRF")
    private BigDecimal ideprf; //regular numeric value

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CODVEO",referencedColumnName = "CODVEO")
    private MuseumEntity codveo; //foreign key

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "CODSBE",referencedColumnName = "CODSBE")
    private RegisterEntity codsbe;// foreign key

}
```

This is my Entity Class:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "DPRF", schema = "dbo")
public class RoleEntity {

    @EmbeddedId
    private RoleIdEntity id;

    @Column(name="DESPROFILI",length = 40)
    private String desprofili;

    @Column(name="DATFINVALPRF")
    private Timestamp datfinvalprf;

    @Column(name="INDAMM")
    private String indamm;

    @Column(name="INDVSZ")
    private String indvsz;

    @Column(name="CODPEN")
    private String codpen;

    @Column(name="DATULTMOD")
    private Timestamp datultmod;

    @Column(name="OPAULTMOD",length = 40)
    private String opaultmod;

    @Column(name="PTN",length = 40)
    private String ptnultmod;

    @Column(name="IDETIPPRFVDA",length = 38)
    private BigDecimal idetipprfvda;

    @Column(name="FLGASSFUN",length = 1)
    private String flgassfun;

    @Column(name="FLGASSOPA",length = 1)
    private String flgassopa;

    @Column(name="FLGMOD", length = 1)
    private String flgmod;

    @Column(name="IDEMLO")
    private BigDecimal idemlo;

    @Column(name="FLGBSE")
    private String flgbse;

}
```

Note: the foreign key and primary key names are the same in the association table and the tables representing MuseumEntity and RegisterEntity.

This is the stacktrace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-14 21:10:15.310 ERROR 57393 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Implicit column reference in the @MapsId mapping fails, try to use explicit referenceColumnNames: it.almaviva.smnadarte.batch.entity.RoleEntity
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at it.almaviva.smnadarte.batch.AdarteBatchApplication.main(AdarteBatchApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Implicit column reference in the @MapsId mapping fails, try to use explicit referenceColumnNames: it.almaviva.smnadarte.batch.entity.RoleEntity
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CopyIdentifierComponentSecondPass.createSimpleProperty(CopyIdentifierComponentSecondPass.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CopyIdentifierComponentSecondPass.doSecondPass(CopyIdentifierComponentSecondPass.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1691) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:295) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Bigdecimal? What's the datatype of the database column?

Comment: datatype is numeric

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA 2 : Implicit column reference in the @MapsId mapping fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642227/jpa-2-implicit-column-reference-in-the-mapsid-mapping-fails)